# Move a group of shapes in Processing

Tags: processing

I have the below code which moves a group of rectangles and circles, but for some reason it always keeps the previous shapes. I want to delete the previous shapes and only draw the new shapes (so it looks like my shapes are moving). I end up with this:

[image]

But it should look like a truck is moving. Below is my code:

```java
   public class Truck extends Vehicle {

     public Truck(float size, float speed) {
         super(size, speed);
     }
     int x = width-250;

    void display() {
        while (x > -100) {
        scale(size); 
        translate(-1, 0);
        fill(255, 0, 0);
        rect(x, 500, 200, 100); //body
        rect(x-75, 525, 75, 75); //front
        fill(0);
        rect(x-75, 525, 45, 45); //window
        ellipse(x-60, 610, 45, 45);
        ellipse(x-20, 605, 35, 35);
        ellipse(x+160, 610, 45, 45);
        ellipse(x+117, 605, 35, 35);
        delay(1);
        x--;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of a disconnected snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have quite a bit of experience with the JavaScript version of processing, and if you add:
`background(255);`
before you draw everything I think that will fix your issue.
This is because the shapes leave a "trail" of sorts behind them when they move. Unless you draw the background periodically, that trail will be visible.

Comment: This is most likely the correct answer, but it would be improved with a small example or an explanation of why this works.